# How to build 32-bit Poco libraries on Mac OS?

Tags: compilation, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling, poco-libraries

I'd like to build 32-bit Poco libraries on Mac OS (since I have other fixed 32-bit dependencies). By default, Poco only builds for the x86_64 target, however.

I tried building Poco like this (according to the Poco build instructions):

```
POCO_TARGET_OSARCH=i386 make
```

However, it still only builds for x86_64. Any ideas?

============================================

Well, it turns out the answer is this (in case anyone else runs into this):

You need to export these two variables before running configure and make:

```
  POCO_TARGET_OSARCH="i386"
  ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"
```

Answer (score 4):

Poco now has a configuration to build 32-bit directly on Mac OS X. Specify `--config=Darwin32`
when running `./configure`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

- gedit poco-1.4.1p1-all/build/config/Darwin
- change these flags to your desired architecture ARCHFLAGS,
  POCO_TARGET_OSARCH

**NOTE** ./configure then only "make".